# how to get the top 1 document of each type, from a search on index(having multiple types)?

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, lucene, nosql

We have an index named "machines", and have types "auto, bike, car, flight" in ElasticSearch

I want to get the similar brands from my search on an index - from every type

How do I query to get the top 1 document of each type, from a search on an index (having multiple types) via the Elasticsearch REST API?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using [top_hits aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html):

```
GET /machines/_search?search_type=count
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {} //your query here
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "top-types": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_type"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_docs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "_score": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```